# Still about how to set configuration files to print the bibliography with Vim and biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, vim

Although I read some posts on this site about `vim` and `biber`, still I'm not able to compile correctly. Following some suggestion, I put in my texcr (at line 96)

```
TexLet g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats = 'pdf,bbl'
```

and at line 126

TexLet g:Tex_BibtexFlavor = 'biber'

Moreover, I changed my compiler.vim this way at lines 567-8:

```
if runCount == 0 && Tex_IsPresentInFile('\\bibdata', mainFileName_root.'.bcf')
let bibFileName = mainFileName_root.'.bbl'
```

However, during the compilation I receive the message:

> LaTeX Warning: Empty Bibliography on line 27

(the line of the source file tex where I put `\printbibliography`).
I find only bcf file, not bbl nor blg
So I really I don'k know what else I can do...

==============================================================================
POSTSCRIPTUM

It works if I change '\bibdata' to 'bibdata'.
What does it mean the double backslash?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not primarily about TeX, is slightly unclear (at least to me) and not least, seems to have been solved by the OP themselves.